# How to make efficient dynamic mask in starling

Tags: actionscript-3, mask, starling-framework

I'm trying to make an interactive book for tablets with animations and **page flip**.

I'm using starling framework.
My idea of page flip is to mask 2 instances of next page with 2 static quads which are moving and rotating (it works great on pc/mac, but slow on tablets).
Using PixelMask is slow/very slow(10-20fps). Using clippedsprite is fast(40-50fps) but cant rotate the mask.

Are there any other options?

**EDIT:**
During my search I've found the idea of shaders (AGAL in ActionScript3), but I'm not familiar with this. Is it possible to simulate masking by the use of GPU shader?

**EDIT2:**
This problem was experienced on iPad1, on iPad3 its 60fps :) Dont know how its going to work on iPad2 and iPad4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure AGAL is the ultimate answer!

But easiest, and still very good, solution is the smart use of ClippedSprites

(Sprites with clipRect since Starling 1.3+)

I've managed to achieve almost static 60 fps on iPad1.

Just needed to remove filters and stop/flatten animations inside Objects!

**Filters are massive performance killers!**

Answer (score 0):

You can find [here](http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/mask-release-date) a mask class based on FragmentFilter. i got better results with it. But if you want to implement a PageFlip, you can use [this](http://www.starlinglib.com/wiki/News%3aStarling_PageFlip) class. And [here](http://kenkao.iteye.com/blog/1900581) is an improved version of the pageflip with interactive corners. Hope it helps you :D